# CSS text-indent does not work in IE when input is a long non-breaking word

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

a simple input element with a text-indent.

`<input style="text-indent:50px;width:100px"/>`

In chrome input a long word will not influence the text-indent like:

[image]

While in IE11, the style is broken like:

[image]

How can i solve the difference to make them look the same?

Comment: I finally figure out why it happen. It is because when you lose focus on input, chrome will set the cursor to the start of input but IE won't. The indent only work for the start of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `padding-left`. Alternatively, try adding `line-height` to make `text-indent` work in IE.

```
<input style="padding-left:50px;width:100px"/>
OR
<input style="text-indent:50px;width:100px;line-height:1"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3jr5eypz/2/

Comment: use padding is somehow different from use text-indent, like when you focus the input and input something, it will use the full input to show the content, the padding won't. line-height not work for this because when you input some word short, the text-indent work in IE11.

Comment: @Loic you can always decrease the `width` with the amount of padding you use.
As for `line-height`, try it with `display:inline-block` or something.